# 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" node error

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to install ionic using node.js. 
when I am running this command I am seeing this error

```
C:\Users\user>npm install -g cordova ionic
'CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\
node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
```

My node cofing is
version: 'v4.7.3',

arch: 'x64',

I am using 64bit window 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this one

> npm install -g ionic cordova

[look into ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/installation/)